# How can I update my WNDR4500 router's firmware if I can't connect to it?

Tags: router

Yesterday my internet went down, and after the cable guy came to troubleshoot the modem he determined there was an issue at the pole.  They sent someone else, the signal started coming in fine... but now for some reason my wireless router seems to be bricked.

It powers on, and the LEDs indicate the firmware is corrupt (blinking green power LED.)  So no idea how that happened, but now I'm trying to figure out how to fix it.

I was thinking I could just install the latest firmware, but I can't connect to the router even with a wired connection to my PC.  It doesn't give an IP address or anything.

I've tried to do a factory reset as well, but that has no apparent effect whatsoever.

So is there anything I can do to get the fresh firmware installed on the router?

Comment: Sounds bricked unless you've got a JTAG cord.

Comment: If its bricked you would have to use a JTAG connector.  Since the process you would use is not guarantee to work and well documented my suggestion is just replace the router.